# set start time and end time php mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I am currently working for Online Election system for my school project and I am having a hard time how to set a start and end time for election. I have a date/time picker for start time and for end time and then I want the value of dtpicker to save in my database and I want to have a countdown based on the time on my database and if the election start it will display the voting page and if the election ends it will redirect to results. How can I do that. I've been a lot of threads but they did not solve my problem. Could you please help me? Do you have any idea or suggest a website related to my problem? I'm stuck on this problem for 3 days. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---UPDATE---

so here is my code below:

```
 <?php
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","vertrigo");
 if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

 mysql_select_db("db_voting", $con);

 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM time WHERE time_ID = 1");

 $numrow = mysql_num_rows($result);

 if ($numrow == 0)
 {
die('No election found.');
 }

 $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
 $startdate = date_format(date_create($row[1]), 'm/d/Y H:i:s');
 echo "Voting will start: " . $startdate. "<br />";

 $closedate = date_format(date_create($row[2]), 'm/d/Y H:i:s');
 echo "Voting will end: " . $closedate;
 ?>
<p>Time Left:
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "<?php echo $closedate ?>";
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "Voting has Ended";
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="countdown.js"></script>
```

so what i am trying to do is whenever the election ends it will redirect to result if not then it will display the voting page. should I use if else statement? I am so sorry, I am still a noob about this. Could you please help me out.?

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you guys! :)

Answer (score 1):

There would be many ways to accomplish this.

Part of the issue you face is that Mysql and PHP can work on different time formats.  If you store the date in date format in MYSQL it will be in YYYY-MM-DD format, while PHP date objects work on a UNIX timestamp (seconds passed since midnight 1 Jan 1970).  You could save a timestamp in the database as a integer, but I normally save in the MYSQL format and then work with the dates in my php code using the php strtotime command. This converts the mysql native format into a timestamp.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Once dates are in this format you just turn the current date into a timestamp and subtract one from the other for your countdown.  You can divide to turn this from seconds to days or whatever.

In terms of turning a timestamp back into a date you can use this function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

One final caveat when working with timestamps, javascript and PHP work handle them differently. Javascript (if you have any in your project) works on milliseconds, php is in seconds.

Just an idea, but there are probably many ways to do this.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you guys! :) @Fooksie

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the reliable way to compare time would be using the Unix time format. Set your if to compare the Unix format of time and see if it works.
Remember to set the default timezone!

And, an example of what you have tried would definitely help.

Comment: I figured it out. Thank you guys! :) @Moe Tsao